# clang-based cross-platform C++ IDE?

Tags: c++, ide, cross-platform, clang

The [clang](http://clang.llvm.org) C++ compiler claims to be built for, among other things, better IDE integration by providing an API for the IDE to use for tasks such as parsing the code.

So, are there are any good C++ IDE's that use clang to provide features such as semantic highlighting, refactoring, and finding and showing semantic errors in real-time?

I've been using Eclipse CDT, but its C++ parser is full of imperfections that cause the IDE to report a lot of annoying false positive errors in the code. I would like to have an IDE that reports an error if and only if the compiler would report the same error, hence my interest in an IDE that's built on a compiler's internals.

I'm primarily interested in cross-platform IDE's, although I wouldn't mind knowing about single-platform ones for Windows or Linux (so **not** Xcode), as long as they are FOSS (another reason why **not** Xcode).

Answer (score 17):

Qt Creator is basing their next-gen code parsing and associated functionality on Clang:

https://www.qt.io/blog/2011/10/19/qt-creator-and-clang

Looks very, very promising!

Comment: Nice catch! Just announced a few days ago, too.

Comment: HighCommander4: it helps if you're on the Clang mailing list ;-)

Comment: I was kind of hoping there would be more... but I guess clang is a fairly young project, and more will come along in time. For the time being, answer accepted :)

Comment: It's worth noting that this effort [has been abandoned](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Clang-based-indexer-and-code-navigator-td4030906.html#a4030923). Apparently the Qt Creator folks found the performance wasn't good enough, and went back to maintaining their own C++ parser.

Comment: @HighCommander4 They certainly haven't abandoned it! That's a post from more than 4 years ago, and guess what? The Clang code model is still there, and even though it uses about 5 times the memory of the old Qt Creator code model, it at least recognizes all the fancy new stuff, and you get Clang's error/warning messages in your IDE. Just te further refute your point, they want to increase Clang's usage in the IDE: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2017/05/24/qt-creator-4-3-0-released/#comment-1199704.

Answer (score 4):

have you tried [clang complete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302)?

if you're punk rock, then vim is enough ide ;)

i often work with xcode so... can't really share firsthand experience, but i knew of its existence.

Comment: @lurscher you're welcome - i am also going attempt to give it a shot this weekend.

Answer (score 4):

[gedit](http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/) isn't really an IDE, but there is a [plugin for it that provides code assistance using clang](https://github.com/GNOME/gedit-code-assistance)

Answer (score 3):

It seems that CodeLite v3.5 [starts](http://www.codelite.org/LiteEditor/ClangIntegration35) supports Clang natively. However I haven't found is it possible to setup LLVM as backend.

Comment: amazing!! please don't refrain yourself from updating this answer if you encounter problems

Answer (score 3):

KDevelop now has clang based c and c++ support, including semantic analysis and autocomplete.  It is primarily for linux but (as of October 2016) has a beta release out for windows and mac as well.

For emacs there are [irony-mode](https://github.com/Sarcasm/irony-mode) and [rtags](https://github.com/Andersbakken/rtags) that provide features such as auto-complete, on fly error checking and jump to symbol.  When combined with [cmake-ide](https://github.com/atilaneves/cmake-ide) they are very powerful tools and one well versed in emacs can be highly productive in this environment.

Answer (score 3):

A relevant new development in this area in the [Language Server Protocol](https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol) (LSP) project, which aims to be a language-agnostic API that allows editors / IDEs to be decoupled from backends that provide code intelligence / analysis.

There is ongoing work to create a clang-based C++ backend called [Clangd](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=LLVM-Clang-Clangd-Server).

There is also ongoing work on [several editors / IDEs](https://github.com/Microsoft/language-server-protocol/wiki/Protocol-Implementations) to support the LSP as a client.

Once the backend implementation matures, all editors supporting the LSP will, in principle, be able to leverage clang's capabilities as exposed through Clangd.

Answer (score 0):

Not FOSS, but JetBrains (of IDEA and ReSharper fame) are building out their AppCode product into a [full C++ IDE supporting Win/Linux/Mac and using clang](http://www.jetbrains.com/objc/features/cpp.html).

[Yes, really](http://blog.jetbrains.com/objc/2013/04/c-ide-an-april-fools-day-joke/).

Comment: Do you have any evidence that this is clang-based, beyond being integrated with the clang static analyzer?

Comment: I don't know whether it uses clang or defers to the platform toolchain for the actual build, but that's not what your original question was about. I'm sure it'll use clang for everything else, though - that's what clang is designed for, and it's not as if there are any viable alternatives.

Comment: I was referring to features like code-completion, code navigation, syntax highlighting, and refactoring being powered by clang. This is not the case for any of the other C++ IDEs I know of - Eclipse, Code::Blocks, CodeLite, NetBeans, KDevelop, Qt Creator - except XCode and the next-gen Qt Creator that @rubenvb was talking about, so that's why I asked.

Comment: It does not seem to use clang for the code model or static analysis or anything else apart from building.

Answer (score 0):

**jucipp**

~900 stars on GitHub in 2019Q2: https://github.com/cppit/jucipp

Now moved to GitLab: https://gitlab.com/cppit/jucipp

Clearly advertises libclang backend as a main feature.